# Correctly supporting only certain screen sizes in Google Play with Android Manifest

Tags: android, xml

I want my app to only be supported on small and medium screens. So this is the code in the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="16"
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

However in the publish page in the google play market the following is shown:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<supports-screens>` is only a filter going down in screen size. So, you could use it to say you only support `large` and `xlarge`, and the Play Store would filter your app out for `small` and `normal` devices. But, going *up* in screen size, `<supports-screens>` just tells the OS to try on its own to make your app work on larger screens.

In addition to `<supports-screens>` (which is useful in its own right), for your filtering purposes, you also need to add [the `<compatible-screens>` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html), to state which screen size buckets and densities that you support.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But there is nothing I can do in API 8?

Comment: @DavidTunnell: Your SDK build target (e.g., Project Properties > Android in Eclipse) needs to be API Level 8 or higher to use `<compatible-screens>`. `<compatible-screens>` has no runtime impact on your app, and *nobody* should be using a build target of API Level 8 at this point in time. Just set your build target to something more current, and let your `<uses-sdk>` element and Lint ensure your backwards compatibility.